# How do I put picture in behind another picture?

Tags: css, z-index

How do `I put twitter in behind facebook?` I `tried` `using z-index,` but it `didnt work.`

http://jsfiddle.net/s4UpL

Comment: #bg img in this class add `position:relative;` then `z-index working`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s4UpL/1/)**

The Code:

```
#bg img{
    z-index: 100 !important;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One !important CSS thing to take away is that `z-index` only applies to positioned elements.

*Sorry, couldn't post this as a comment to Nathan Lee's answer.*

Comment: You can drop the exclamation mark. The answer was not about `important`. The crucial part was to emphasize that `z-index` will only work on `positioned` elements, which was not part of the original code.

Comment: That is why it had to be added and at the same time it was recommended. Weather `!important` was declared or not, the OP already had it.